# Euclidean lemma proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, divisibility

According to Euclidean lemma it is defined that if $p$ is prime then $$p|ab\Rightarrow p|a\lor p|b$$
How to prove by descending induction that if $$p|a^n \Rightarrow p|a $$ 
knowing that $a^n = a \times a^{n-1}$

If there is an easier solution don't hesitate to post

Comment: Original problem :Show that if a prime number p|a^n then p|a

Comment: Sorry overlooked that $p$ is prime :s...

Answer (score 2):

You could do it that way :

$$a^n=a^{n-1}*a\ ,$$

so either p divides a or $a^{n-1}$.

Continue until n=1.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $p$ does not divide $a= p_1^{k_1} \cdots p_l^{k_l}$, this means that there is no prime divisor of $a$ that equals $p$.  $a^n=  (p_1^{k_1} \cdots p_l^{k_l})^n$, so $p$ is not a divisor of $a^n$ either. The theorem holds by contraposition.

Comment: It may not be easier, but it's a different approach, so maybe you find this answer interesting as well.